# I'm a bit confused on how to linearize an Exponential Graph

Tags: exponential-function, least-squares, linear-regression, linearization, desmos

I've seen other people answer questions on how to do this, I tried it and it didn't work. As of right now, I'm using the following desmos graphs.

[Desmos, Exponential Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hbslck8duy)

[Desmos, Linearized Exponential Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5v74rykvks)

I'm using $Y=ab^X$ as my exponential graph. I'm then using the least squares regression method, so:

$ln(Y)=ln(ab^X)$

$ln(Y)=ln(a)+X ln(b)$

Now that it's in form $Y=mX+b$, where $ln(Y)=Y, m=ln(b), b=ln(a)$. I then used [the Least Square Regression Method](https://www.cuemath.com/data/least-squares/), but the parameters in the line of best fit don't match up. Why not?

[image: Linearized Graph with the parameters from the line of best fit]

[image: Exponential Graph with both lines of best fit]

From what I understand the issue might be due to the fact that the data is not perfect.

[image: Process for getting the values]
[image: Math and values]

Comment: Can you point out which parameters don't match up please?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I updated the question to include a lot more information, I think that it's because the data is not perfectly exponential. The actual data that I used comes from [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/global-plastics-production)

Comment: try to ask in Stats StackExchange as well

Comment: Why would they be the same anyway? If you're linearizing an exponential graph, then the residuals of the linearized graph correspond to the **multiplicative** increase, not the actual (additive) increase. That means in a linearized plot, 0.01 is just as close to 1 as 100, even though their differences are not. This also explains why the orange curve approximates better for smaller values of Y.